# Get value from json in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have this json

```
"urls": {
      "title1": {
        "url": "someurl1"
      },
      "title12": {
        "url": "someurl2"
      }
    }
```

I want get title and value of url out in an element for each. 
Something like this

```
$.each(value.urls, function (key, value) {
    $('.log-list-js').append('<a href="'+ title +'">'+ someurl +'</a>');
});
```

Hope it makes sense.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
   var values = {
        "urls": {
            "title1": {
                "url": "someurl1"
            },
            "title12": {
                "url": "someurl2"
            }
        }
    }
    for (var key in values.urls) {
        $('.log-list-js').append('<a href="' + values.urls[key].url + '">' + values.urls[key].url + '</a>');
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vya55/)

Comment: Thanks, but what about the title? That should be the text of each element?

Comment: I found out 'key' : )

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.log-list-js').append('<a href="' + value.urls[key].url + '">' + value.urls[key].url + '</a>');
```

This is format

Answer (score 0):

Your json should be converted to object first, use JSON.parse method if you are having a json string. object should something like this

```
urls = {
      "title1": {
      "url": "someurl1"
      },
      "title12": {
        "url": "someurl2"
      }
    };
```

then your method is correct with some corrections to the code

```
$.each(urls, function(index, value){
    $('.log-list-js').append('<a href="'+ index +'">'+ value.url +'</a>');
});
```

here is the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zmMAL/)** on jsfiddle